# Как модифицировать этот bash script, чтобы избежать вложенного цикла?

Tags: shell, sh

Здраствуйте, помогите пожалуйста модифицировать код, чтобы избежать двойного цикла. Заранее спасибо за любую идею.

```
#!/bin/sh
for pheno in `cat /wrk/abc/composition/results/list.txt`
do
    header=`head -1 /wrk/abc/composition/results/"$pheno"/meta_"$pheno".out`
    echo "pheno $header" > results.txt
    for pheno in `cat /wrk/abc/composition/results/list.txt`
    do
        awk -v p="$pheno" 'NR == FNR{a[$1]; next}($3) in a{print p, $0}' list.txt /wrk/abc/composition/results/"$pheno"/meta_"$pheno".out >> results.txt
    done
done
```